# Initialization for References C++

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, initialization

I recently started learning C++ and stumbled upon this issue.
Pardon me if it sounds dumb but why can't we initialize a value to a reference variable through

```
int r= 20;
int &ref = r;
ref(20);
```

although this method of initializing value of 20 works when not using it as a reference variable.

IDE: C++11

Why is this so?

Comment: In your example it was initialized on line 2. For line 3 you can just assign a new value with `ref = 20`.

Comment: Or did you mean to ask why you can't do `int& ref(20)`?

Comment: @Muscampester I know we can use `ref=20` but I did not get it why can't we use `ref(20)`.

Comment: You can't use that for the int either, not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you would like to do that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> although this method of initializing value of 20 works when not using it as a reference variable.

In what sense it works? Now for compiler `ref(20);` looks like a function call, if you change `int &ref` to `int ref`, you will still get the same error.

I think you meant that `int r(20);` does work. In case of references, they must first be bound to an variable which they reference, this make it not possible to bind to variable and at the same assign a value - if that is what you ask about.

Comment: Thanks I lot, I understood what I was doing wrong.  When I was initializing `r(20)` the compiler thought I was passing a value to a function.